# how to save the datas which are get from a newsletter?

Tags: html, css, web, newsletter

I have made a newsletter with html and css,and in my newsletter,there are 4 fields,text boxes I mean,such as users name,family name,phone number and email address.I want to know that how should I save these informations which I get from the user in my newsletter. Should I save them on an excel file on the host?or what?what should I do?I will be so thankful for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to add forms in emails, they require server side code and database to work. You should link to a web based form so the email recipient can click and go to the form online to fill it in.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a server side language to store the data on a server, like PHP.

Comment: I know,but where should I save them?

Comment: Yes, you would need a database. Alternatively you could set up a web page with a form that saves to a google doc - this is easy but less advanced than say using php. See here: http://www.google.com/google-d-s/createforms.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead link to a [wufoo](http://wufoo.com) or [google forms](http://www.google.com/google-d-s/createforms.html). You cannot embed a form in your email (yet).